# How to update a public uint variable directly from hardhat unit test in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, ethereumjs, testing

I want to update public variable abc to 2.

```
contract ABC {

    uint public abc = 1;

    function updateABC() public {
        abc = 2;
    }
}
```

And want to write Unit test to check if it was updated to 2 or not.

```
it("Should be updated to 2", async () => {
            const {ownerInstance} = await loadFixture(deployOwnerControlsFixture);
            ownerInstance.connect.abc = 2;
            expect(ownerInstance.abc()).equals(2);
 });
```

But this is not working, its throwing error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I'm trying something like this

```
ownerInstance.connect(owner).abc = 2;
let aa = await ownerInstance.abc();
console.log("Updated value of abc",aa);
expect(await ownerInstance.abc()).equal(3);
```

I'm seeing error[![enter image description here][2]][2]

We can see clearly the value of abc is not updating to 2.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhTc.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83jxD.png

Answer (score 0):

To update a public uint variable you need to call the function that updates the variable - in your case, you can call the `updateABC()` function to update the abc variable to 2. We also `await` the `ownerInstance` as its an async function. Then also check if the variable got updated with `to.equal(2)`.

### Code

```js
it("Should be updated to 2", async () => {
    const { ownerInstance } = await loadFixture(deployOwnerControlsFixture);
    await ownerInstance.updateABC();
    expect(await ownerInstance.abc()).to.equal(2);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @timsntech, what if I want to assign 3 to variable abc, we can definitely pass through function parameters and then can update abc and then we can test that, but I want this without calling  updateABC() function.
`code`
it("Should be updated to 3", async () => {
            const {ownerInstance} = await loadFixture(deployOwnerControlsFixture);
            ownerInstance.connect.abc = 3;
            expect(ownerInstance.abc()).equals(3);
 });

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are comparing BigNum and Num. Try this:

```
expect(ownerInstance.abc().toNumber()).equals(2);
```

Comment: now its showing TypeError: ownerInstance.abc(...).toNumber is not a function.